# MpAndroidChart - How to set the same space between the x-axis label?

Tags: charts, mpandroidchart

According we can see in this image, the size of the last x-axis area is less that the others. With this, the Sunday looks less that the other days of week..

How can I put he same distance between the x-axis grid?

[image]

I'm drawing 4 points for each day of week. So, my X-values are

`{Mo,Mo,Mo,Mo, Tu,Tu,Tu,Tu ... Sun,Sun,Sun,Sun}`

and

```
xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may enable the  horizontal scroll bar by

```
lineChart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```